# WPF Access to Expander inside a ControlTemplate of an ItemControl with GroupDescription

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol

In my view, I have an ItemControl:

```xaml
<Border Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,5,0,0">
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <ItemsControl Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding Blocks}">
                <ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate>
                                            <Expander IsExpanded="True" Style="{StaticResource ClassicExpander}">
                                                <Expander.Header>
                                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                        <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                                                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                                                   FontSize="14">
                                                            <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                                            <Run Text="(" /><Run Text="{Binding ItemCount, Mode=OneWay}" /><Run Text=")" />
                                                        </TextBlock>
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </Expander.Header>
                                                <ItemsPresenter />
                                            </Expander>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Border>
```

In my view model, I use groupDescription to group my item in the item :

```
private void _SortBlockList()
    {
        Debug.Assert(Blocks != null);
        InitializeCollectionViewSource();
        var groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription(nameof(FunctionBlock.Category));
        _BlockView.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
    }
```

I want to create a button to collapse all the Expanders in the ControlTemplate but I don't know how I can access all the Expanders.

Can some nice people help me? Thanks.

Comment: In your Item Template, Bind the Expander.IsExpanded property to a Bool variable in the ViewModel. Next, in the Command for the button set the Bool property to true/false and accordingly the expanders would update.

Comment: Lets start by giving the expander some name, like `x:Name="PART_Expander"`. Then it would be good if you show your current attempts at getting the `GroupItem` and the `Expander` within

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava while this suggestion works it's making the viewmodel responsible for purely view related stuff. Not really a no-go but not the cleanest of all possible solutions.

Comment: That is true, I wanted the OP to derive & extend the VM solution into a Trigger (within xaml). Rather than using the Button, they can use a CheckBox (re-style it to look like a Button) and bind the Expander.IsExpanded to the CheckBox.Checked property. -- My intent was just to give a hint over which they can build. :)

Comment: I try with "GetTemplateChild("PART_Expander")" on the method OnApplyTemplate that i override but always returns null.

Comment: The problem with the biding to IsExpanded property is that the data context in the group is not the same than the itemsControl

Comment: I don't see overriden `OnApplyTemplate` in your question.

Comment: Because I tried different solution, so I put only what i'm sure

Comment: But because you don't show more than what you are sure about, you leave more work to those who might be willing to answer your question. Why would I develop the code to get `GroupItem` as a precondition to getting the `Expander`, if you already know how to get it?